# sqlite3 IOS query bugging table

Tags: ios, sql, xcode, sqlite

i have this odd bug where i'm querying my table 'Children' with quite a complex query.  It works fine, but for some reason it bugs a this other view from updating the database.  You see this database holds stickers and one easy way to give them is to access this admin page, which is where its bugging.  I can query the information fine, BUT ! when i update the table it hates and doesn't work.  But its strange inside the core view controller it doesn't bug when i update the table there.  I narrowed down the code to the cause of this problem:

```
-(void)leaderboardsystem
{  
    NSString *nexttargetsql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM Children WHERE Completed > %d OR (Completed = %d AND Current_Stickers > %d) ORDER BY Completed ASC, Current_Stickers ASC LIMIT 1",completecount,completecount,stickercount]; //Queries table for the childs name and returns more data.
    NSString *behindyousql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM Children WHERE Completed < %d OR (Completed = %d AND Current_Stickers < %d) ORDER BY Completed DESC, Current_Stickers DESC LIMIT 1",completecount,completecount,stickercount];

    nexttarget.text = [self leaderboardQuery:nexttargetsql];
    behindyou.text = [self leaderboardQuery:behindyousql];

    }


-(NSString*)leaderboardQuery:(NSString*)sql//does the querying
{
    sqlite3_stmt *statement;
    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(Childdb, [sql UTF8String], -1, &statement, nil)==SQLITE_OK) {
        while (sqlite3_step(statement)==SQLITE_ROW) {
            char *ffield1 = (char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0);
            NSString *ffield1Str = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:ffield1];
            char *ffield2 = (char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 8);
            NSString *ffield2Str = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:ffield2];
            char *ffield3 = (char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 10);
            NSString *ffield3Str = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:ffield3];
            NSLog(@"Name:%@",ffield1Str);
            NSLog(@"this is completecount: %@", ffield2Str);
            NSLog(@"this is stickcount: %@",ffield3Str);
            return ffield1Str;
        }

    }
        return NULL;
}
```

whenever i call the method leaderboardsystem it causes this bug, but if i don't then it works fine !  funny enough, i was a little surprised to be honest.  It surprises me because it affects a completely different view controller that has no connection to the main view.  The table layout is:

```
[self createTable:@"Children" withField1:@"Name" withField2:@"Password" withField3:@"House" withField4:@"Sticker Collection" withField5:@"Tickets Gathered" withField6:@"Tickets Removed" withField7:@"Last Ticket Scanned" withField8:@"Current Tickets" withField9:@"Completed" withField10:@"Complete" withField11:@"Current_Stickers"];
```

This is the updating code that seems to fail when i include the leaderboard system in the main view(this is on a completely different view controller)

```
-(void)UpdateDatabase//update table, if value has been incremented
{
    NSString *sql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"UPDATE Children SET 'Current Tickets' = %d, 'Tickets Removed' = %d, 'Tickets Gathered' = %d WHERE Name = '%@'",[self.currenttickets.text integerValue], [self.removedtickets.text integerValue], [self.totaltickets.text integerValue], name];
    [self updatetable:sql];
}

-(void)updatetable:(NSString*)sql
{
    char *err;
    if (sqlite3_exec(Childdb, [sql UTF8String], NULL, NULL, &err)!=SQLITE_OK) {
        sqlite3_close(Childdb);
        NSAssert(0, @"Could not update Table");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Table updated");
    }
}
```

I'm trying not to overload the description here and keeping it brief my program is quite large, if you require any more information let me know.  BUT i guarantee that the leaderboard system is causing the problem.  Thanks a million if you can solve this problem, been working on it all day ! :(

ALSO it also disturbs the place where i add records to the table, so the updating code is not causing it.  Its that leaderboard query, no idea why :(

Answer (score 0):

Okay, well i didn't want to do this.  But instead of having a method to manage the query, i just repeated it twice, inside the method, but it worked !  Not sure what was wrong with it.  Seems no one else could help me so, i'll just leave it to that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `sqlite3_finalize(Childdb)`. It would look something like the following:

```
-(NSString*)leaderboardQuery:(NSString*)sql//does the querying
{
    sqlite3_stmt *statement;
    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(Childdb, [sql UTF8String], -1, &statement, nil)==SQLITE_OK) {
        while (sqlite3_step(statement)==SQLITE_ROW) {
           ...
        }
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(Childdb);
    return NULL;
}
```

This is a really simple example because there is no error handling. The documentation that describes this is the following (located [here](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/prepare.html)):

> *ppStmt is left pointing to a compiled prepared statement that can be executed using sqlite3_step(). If there is an error, *ppStmt is set to
>   NULL. If the input text contains no SQL (if the input is an empty
>   string or a comment) then *ppStmt is set to NULL. The calling
>   procedure is responsible for deleting the compiled SQL statement using
>   sqlite3_finalize() after it has finished with it. ppStmt may not be
>   NULL.

This example code may help you: https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb/blob/master/src/FMDatabase.m#L519